# How to use ts-migrate to convert JS files to TS using the JSDoc annotations

Tags: javascript, typescript, ts-migrate

I want to use [ts-migrate](https://github.com/airbnb/ts-migrate) to convert some of my projects from JS to TS. This tool seems to have a plugin to use JSDoc annotations to produce types, but I have no idea of how to tell it to use such plugin.

On my current project I have JSDoc annotations for almost all the files. How can I make ts-migrate take those JSDoc comments into account? It will really speed up my work.

Answer (score 1):

It is done through the (currently undocumented) option flag `--plugin jsdoc`:

```
npx ts-migrate-full . --plugin jsdoc
```

It does however [leave the JSDoc comment unaltered](https://github.com/airbnb/ts-migrate/issues/128).

The plugin does not annotate `@returns` unless a `annotateReturns` option flag is set; I am unable to figure out how to set it but you can get annotated returns by changing `const returnType = annotateReturns ? ...` to `const returnType = true ? ...` in `node_modules/ts-migrate-plugins/build/src/plugins/jsdoc.js`.